# ConfigurationManager class not available

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationmanager

[image]

I am not able to get the connectionString from App.Config file..

Am I missing something?

after creating the class, I moved the class into some folder..Is that the issue? what is the solution without moving the class?

Comment: Have you tried to compile? Occasionally VS gets hung up and doesn't recognize things - but on compile it works fine

Comment: @Prescott: Ya..but still not working..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Configuration.dll`.

Menu Bar -> Project -> Add Reference... -> .NET (Tab) -> System.Configuration -> OK

Answer (score 4):

Add references to your website as **System.Web.Configuration** and **System.Configuration** and it will work.

Comment: as a desktop application, System.Web.Configuration should not be referenced.